# Phalcon : get instance of controller in beforeExecuteRoute

Tags: phalcon

How can i get instance of the exciting controllers in `beforeExecuteRoute` method of the `phalcon` framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exciting controllers? It all depends on what excited them…

But srsly, you can only get the instance of the active controller from the dispatcher, that can be accessed like this:

```
$controller = $di->getShared('dispatcher')->getActiveController();
```

If you are using event handler with event manager, than like this:

```
$eventManager->attach("dispatch:beforeExecuteRoute", function (Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher) {
    $controller = $dispatcher->getActiveController();
});
```

If you actually meant existing controllers as plural, then you'd need to add some sort of tracking for controller instantiation. You can't do this via `__construct` in your controller classes, because for some reason some genius marked `__construct` as `final`. The other option would be to add that tracking in your `beforeExecuteRoute` and `beforeNotFoundAction` event, dig [the code in the repository](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/33e85f551c253ddff58e594e2bace5c2e55f12ef/ext/dispatcher.c#L790) for details:

```
// Exciting controllers get stored whenever the dispatcher reports if the action was not found
// or when it's ready to dispatch. Note, if a controller gets created outside the dispatcher
// it will not be tracked, though in real life that should never happen.

$controller = [];

$eventManager->attach("dispatch:beforeNotFoundAction", function (Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher) {
    $controllers[] = $dispatcher->getActiveController();
});

$eventManager->attach("dispatch:beforeExecuteRoute", function (Event $event, Dispatcher $dispatcher) {
    $controllers[] = $dispatcher->getActiveController();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Phalcon\Mvc\Micro, I'm sorry to tell you that it's hard to get the right answer.I had a similar problem before, so I analyzed $event and $app using PHP's reflection mechanism and came up with the following answer:

```
<?php

    $eventsManager = new \Phalcon\Events\Manager();
    $eventsManager->attach(
        'micro:beforeExecuteRoute',
        function (\Phalcon\Events\Event $event, $app) {
            $controllerName = $event->getSource()->getActiveHandler()[0]->getDefinition();
            $actionName = $event->getSource()->getActiveHandler()[1];
        }
    );

    $app = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Micro($di);
    $app->setEventsManager($eventsManager);
```